# how run an action after executing the action of control (in all of the pages)

Tags: zend-framework, plugins, dispatcher, front-controller

I have a plugin for frontcontroller.

It works fine for dispatcherloodstartup method, but postdispatcher can't call action!

What is wrong?

This is my plugin:

```
class Places_Controller_Plugin_ActionSetup extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{

public function dispatchLoopStartup( Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        
        if (!$front->hasPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack')) {
                $actionStack = new Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack();
                $front->registerPlugin($actionStack, 97);
            } else {
            $actionStack = $front->getPlugin('Zend_Controller_Plugin_ActionStack');
        }
        
            $menuAction = clone($request);
            $menuAction->setActionName('menu')->setControllerName('index');
            $actionStack->pushStack($menuAction);
        
    }
     

    public function postDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {     $menuAction = clone($request);
        $menuAction->setActionName('toolbar')->setControllerName('index');
    }
}
```

this is my bootstrap code:

```
$frontController->registerPlugin(new Places_Controller_Plugin_ActionSetup(), 98);
```

if I must make use of stackpush, which number is useful?

Comment: no , but i`m sure toolbar action don`t work!

Comment: postdispatch metod work, if there was a prob, i'm sure prob is in this code : `$menuAction = clone($request); $menuAction->setActionName('toolbar')->setControllerName('index'); ` for example this code work in postdispatch metod without prob! `$this->getResponse()->appendBody("<p>postDispatch() alled</p>\n");`

Comment: It looks like your `postDispatch()` method clones the request object, makes changes _on the clone_, and then exits. So no surprise that it ends up having no effect.

Comment: if i remove clone function it show me just white page, without anything!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First. This is a bad practise. You have to do 3 dispatch roundabouts (all plugins pre- and post-dispatch, controllers pre&post, ...)- If possible I would switch to one front controller plugin, that will fill the appropriate layout variables and use partials/view helpers to render them.

The problem with your code is that in postDispatch() your request has already `isDispatched = true`, which means it won't be dispatched again. Option might be to create the request yourself. And then push it to the actionstack.

Also you can use actionstack methods `$this->actionstack($action, $controller, $module, $params)`, that will create the request for you ;) You can get the current params like this `$params = $frontController->getRequest()->getParams()` or sth. like that (not 100% sure about the method name).

**EDIT:**

If you put the toolbar rendering into layout, then there is no problem. You can assign the variables to the view and they will be ready in layout.  You'll just have `echo $this->render('toolbar.phtml');` and that's all. It will always be rendered after all actions are rendered as layout is the last view rendered. Just make sure your toolbar variables don't collide with other variables (good idea is to refix them with something - say `$this->toolbarUsername;$this->toolbarIsLogged`, etc.)

Comment: 1 question: if i have more plugins my site will be slow and it`s better i put all codes in one plugin??

Comment: i can do your solution but there is a prob! variables that will show in toolbar assigning in controllers action, so i need toolbar render be after action running,what is your idea?!

Comment: Yeah, many plugins + many request roundabouts = very slow. See edit.